# android whole activity gets reloaded while updating a single fragment

Tags: android, imageview, zooming, fragment

I am new to fragments, I have 2 fragments one of which is a ListFragment. the lisview inside this fragment contains a list of devices and gets populated using the database curser adapter.The other fragment contains an imageview. Issue is that whenever there is some update in DB (related to any device), the device list fragment gets updated (which is fine), but along with the the second fragment also gets reloaded or refreshed whatever. All the zooming gets lost and the image comes back to its original size.

Please help, I have been wasting a lot of time over this.

Comment: What does you mean under "get updated"? Anyway you should to provide code if you want to receive right answer.

Comment: the listfragment shows some details of the devices. whenever I update any row corresponding to a device in database, the listfragment gets refreshed

Comment: Are both fragments on the screen at the same time or does this occur when you transition to the imageview fragment?

Comment: Both the fragments are on the screen at that time